# C#: Is it possible to conditionally exclude some files from compilation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight

I would like to conditionally compile a project excluding specific classes. Is it possible?

**UPDATE:**

Basically what I'm looking for is to decrease the size of resulting .xap file through command-line directive by not compiling in specific classes (stored in separate .cs files) and all their dependencies.

Here is how [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z0wd3d7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) recommends to do it manually. If there was a way to do it conditionally in an automated manner, that'd be a perfect solution.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'excluding'.

Comment: I don't think MSIL code is that big. Even with thousands of classes, it shouldn't be bigger than few megabytes. I would suspect you have other resources, that have big filesezes.

Comment: It's for web, even megabyte is big enough to care.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Project file `ProjectName.cproj` is a plain xml file containing project properties and compiler instructions. Files to include are listed between `<ItemGroup>...</ItemGroup>` tags. There can be one or more such `<ItemGroup>` listings. So everything you have to do is put files that you want to be compiled in conditionally, into a separate `<ItemGroup>` and add a condition as attribute:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(BUILD)' == 'IMAGE' ">
    <Compile Include="PngEncoder\Adler32.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PngEncoder\CRC32.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PngEncoder\Deflater.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PngEncoder\DeflaterConstants.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PngEncoder\DeflaterEngine.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PngEncoder\DeflaterHuffman.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PngEncoder\DeflaterOutputStream.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PngEncoder\DeflaterPending.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PngEncoder\IChecksum.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PngEncoder\PendingBuffer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PngEncoder\PngEncoder.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now this group of files will be included only if there is a property defined with the name of `BUILD` and the value of `"IMAGE"`. Properties can be defined in the project file itself:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.50727</ProductVersion>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Or passed in from command-line:

```
msbuild ProjectName.cproj /p:BUILD=IMAGE
```

`msbuild.exe` comes with **.NET Framework**.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`ConditionalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) for this:

> Indicates to compilers that a method call or attribute should be ignored unless a specified conditional compilation symbol is defined.

```
[Conditional("SomeCondition")]
public void WillCompileOnlyIfSomeConditionIsDefined()
{
}
```

An alternative is to use [preprocessor directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx):

```
#if !SomeCondition
  // will only compile if SomeCondition is false
#endif
```

Comment: According to the documentation, this attribute is only valid on a class if the class is a descendant of `System.Attribute`.

Comment: I tried, but the size of resulting .xap file doesn't decrease. And then it is too cumbersome to add directives to each file (there are whole namespaces included).

Comment: @jayarjo - I'm afraid I know very little about silverlight.

Comment: Note that the `ConditionalAttribute` only removes calls to the method. The method is still compiled and included in the IL.

Answer (score 1):

On builds with Visual Studio Online condition attributes are ignored in ItemGroup elements.

As described [here](https://whathecode.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/conditional-project-or-library-reference-in-visual-studio/), using `When/Choose/Otherwise` attributes are supported.

```
 <Choose>
     <When Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug With Project References'">
       <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\SomeProject\SomeProject.csproj">
        <Project>{6CA7AB2C-2D8D-422A-9FD4-2992BE62720A}</Project>
        <Name>SomeProject</Name>
      </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
      <Otherwise>
        <ItemGroup>
           <Reference Include="SomeProject">
             <HintPath>..\Libraries\SomeProject.dll</HintPath>
           </Reference>
         </ItemGroup>
       </Otherwise>
    </Choose>
```